# spring + hibernate: manually commit the transaction at end

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, autocommit

I am using spring mvc and hibernate

```
@Controller
public class COACategoriesController {

protected static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(COACategoriesController.class);


@Resource(name="COACategoriesService")
private COACategoriesService obj_coacs;
@Resource(name="COAMaintenanceService")
private COAMaintenanceService obj_coams;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/addCoaCategory", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String addCoaCategory(@RequestParam("conCatName") String coaCatName, Model model) {

     Date sysdate = null;
     String Message="";
     try{

     sysdate = new Date();


     COACategoriesModel model1 = new COACategoriesModel( coaCatName, 1, "", sysdate , 0);

     COAMaintenanceModel account =  new COAMaintenanceModel();
        account.setDiscription("Test Description");
        account.setCategoryId(model1);

        Message="Fail-First";
        obj_coacs.AddCOACategories(model1);


        Message="Fail-Second";
        obj_coams.AddCOAMaintenance (account);


        Message="Add Successfully";
     }catch(Exception ex){
         log.error("Exception.."+ex);
         model.addAttribute("success", Message);
     }



        return "fin/category";
    }



}
```

How I commit the transaction manually as all the transactions save successfully, if any transaction fails to insert , rollback all the transactions in catch block. ?

I am using spring mvc and hibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer to create a separate method (combining your 2 methods) in some service to handle all necessary transactions there.

Comment: yes! this solve the problem that currently i am facing. but can you tell me please that if there is any way to without combining 2 method. Actually in hibernate i can easily commit and rollback the transaction  but after integration with spring mvc , I am in problem. ?

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor did you try using "@TransactionConfiguration( defaultRollback = false )"? I think Alexey is right, you may need to break it down in two (or more) methods. Alternatively, you can try to get your TransactionManager using Spring dependency injection or implement your own TransactionManager with manual commit/rollback. However, I personally do not really like this alternative.

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor, complementing my previous comment:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic

Answer (score 1):

First the property `connection.autocommit` needs to be set to `false`, to enable transaction level commit.

This can be done by adding

```
<property name="connection.autocommit">false</property>
```

in `hibernate.cfg.xml`

secondly, use the following kind of code at your DAO level

```
Session s = null;
Transaction t = null;
try {
  s = getSessionFactory().openSession();
  t = s.beginTransaction();
  // code to persist the object

}
catch(HibernateException he) {
  if(t != null) {
     t.rollback();
  }
}
finally {
  if(s != null) {
    s.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Exception: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here , because I am using Spring + Hibernate